# Assigning Key from Kendo Grid row to main Model within a View

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui, grid

Using Kendo Grid in an MVC application.

The primary model for the View (PlanViewModel) contains a property which is a foreign key to another entity (BuildingId) For instance,

public class PlanViewModel
{

```
public int PlanId { get; set; }
public string PlanName { get; set; }
public int BuildingId { get; set; }
...
```

}

The Building ID is to be populated by the selected row of a BuildingGrid on the View.

So with the BuildingGrid, I'm using the .Selectable setting to invoke an onChange event.  How in the following event would I update the model.BuildingId

```
function onChange(arg) {
    var selected = $.map(this.select(), function (item) {
        return $(item).text();
    });

    /// UPDATE MODEL BuildingId here

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. First, I associated an Html attribute to the model property like so:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.BuildingID, new {id = "Id"})
```

Then I added the following jquery script:

```
$('#BuildingGrid').click(function() {
    var gview = $(this).data("kendoGrid");
    var selectedItem = gview.dataItem(gview.select());
    var BuildingId = selectedItem.BuildingId;
    $("#Id").val(BuildingId);
});
```

That set the Model.BuildingId perfectly.

Thanks to a tip I got from here: [set a value to model using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520789/set-a-value-to-model-using-jquery)